# Drawing and animating lines around a circle

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation, core-graphics

I am new to Core Graphics and want to draw a circle and lines around it in all directions and animating giving a feel of rays coming out of the circle. The

Please suggest as how to achieve the line animation effect in all directions of a circle.

My so far code to draw a circle is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)iRect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef aContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawMeWithContext:aContext withRect:iRect];
    [self drawBadgeGradientWithContext:aContext withRect:iRect];


}



- (void)drawMeWithContext:(CGContextRef)iContext withRect:(CGRect)iRect {
    CGContextSaveGState(iContext);

    CGFloat aRadius = CGRectGetMaxY(iRect) * kBadgeCornerRadius;
    CGFloat aBuffer = CGRectGetMaxY(iRect) * kScreenBuffer;
    CGFloat aMaxX = CGRectGetMaxX(iRect) - aBuffer;
    CGFloat aMaxY = CGRectGetMaxY(iRect) - aBuffer;
    CGFloat aMinX = CGRectGetMinX(iRect) + aBuffer;
    CGFloat aMinY = CGRectGetMinY(iRect) + aBuffer;

    CGContextBeginPath(iContext);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(iContext, [_MyColor CGColor]);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMaxX - aRadius, aMinY + aRadius, aRadius, M_PI + M_PI/2, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMaxX - aRadius, aMaxY - aRadius, aRadius, 0, M_PI/2, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMinX + aRadius, aMaxY - aRadius, aRadius, M_PI/2, M_PI, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMinX + aRadius, aMinY + aRadius, aRadius, M_PI, M_PI + M_PI/2, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(iContext);
    CGContextFillPath(iContext);
    CGContextRestoreGState(iContext);
}


- (void)drawBadgeGradientWithContext:(CGContextRef)iContext withRect:(CGRect)iRect {
    CGContextSaveGState(iContext);

    CGFloat aRadius = CGRectGetMaxY(iRect) * kBadgeCornerRadius;
    CGFloat aBuffer = CGRectGetMaxY(iRect) * kScreenBuffer;
    CGFloat aMaxX = CGRectGetMaxX(iRect) - aBuffer;
    CGFloat aMaxY = CGRectGetMaxY(iRect) - aBuffer;
    CGFloat aMinX = CGRectGetMinX(iRect) + aBuffer;
    CGFloat aMinY = CGRectGetMinY(iRect) + aBuffer;

    CGContextBeginPath(iContext);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMaxX - aRadius, aMinY + aRadius, aRadius, M_PI+(M_PI/2), 0, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMaxX - aRadius, aMaxY - aRadius, aRadius, 0, M_PI/2, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMinX + aRadius, aMaxY - aRadius, aRadius, M_PI/2, M_PI, 0);
    CGContextAddArc(iContext, aMinX + aRadius, aMinY + aRadius, aRadius, M_PI, M_PI+M_PI/2, 0);
    CGContextClip(iContext);

    size_t aNumberOfLocations = 2;
    CGFloat aLocations[2] = {0.0, 0.5};
//  CGFloat aComponents[8] = {0.98, 0.96, 0.98, 1.0, 0.698, 0.016, 0.075, 1.0};

    CGColorSpaceRef aColorSpace;
    CGGradientRef aGradient;
    aColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    aGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (aColorSpace, _MyColorComponent, aLocations, aNumberOfLocations);
    CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
    CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGPoint aStartPoint;
    CGPoint anEndPoint;
    aStartPoint.x = 0;
    aStartPoint.y = 0;
    anEndPoint.x = 0;
    anEndPoint.y = aMaxY;

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient (iContext, aGradient, aStartPoint, anEndPoint, 0);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(aColorSpace);
    CGGradientRelease(aGradient);
    CGContextRestoreGState(iContext);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you wanted to draw six lines. The circumference of the unit circle is 2π. Therefore, the first line will have a rotation of π/3 radians (that is 2π divided by 6), the second line will have a rotation of 2π/3 radians, etc. Apply that rotation to each line.

Now you need to translate your lines to the outside of the circle. Well, you know the angle on the circle where you want each line to go (π/3, 2π/3 ... 2π), and the radius of the circle. Therefore, you can create a polar coordinate (e.g. (radius, π/3)). Convert this polar point to a cartesian point (e.g. (1, 2)). How do you do this? Here's how.

To get your x coordinate, find cos(π/3), and then multiply that by the radius. Do the same thing for y, but use sin instead.

(2, π/3) is polar => (2cos(π/3), 2sin(π/3)) is cartesian.

Now that you have your x and y coordinate pair, translate each line to its cartesian point. Now you need to animate the lines. I'm not too familiar with rotation abilities on iOS. Can you rotate each line about the center of the circle? Otherwise, you have to recalculate the point on the circle where each line should go to next, and rotate the lines themselves.

This involves a decent amount of math. Let me know if you need additional help.